# Request.Url.Host is wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net

While attemtping to debug some old website, I've been banging my head against a rather ridiculous wall.

In my HOSTS file, I have

```
127.0.0.1 local.dev.site.tld
```

When I navigate it in my browser, `Request.Url.Host` keeps being `localhost` instead of `local.dev.site.tld`

This is needed to determine things like language, like if `.tld` is `.de == Germany` or `.dk == Denmark`. Unfortunately I cannot change all the calls to `Request.Url.Host`. But it should just work, shouldn't it..?

Some say it's the browser's "fault", cause it'd have `localhost` in the host-header, but Fiddler tells me that said header is `local.dev.site.tld`.

My google-foo isn't very strong, so forgive me if I've missed some obvious solution or SO post.

So, how do I make the right hostname appear in `Request.Url.Host`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Request\["host"\] == "dev.testhost.com:1234" whereas Request.Url.Host == "localhost"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941522/why-does-requesthost-dev-testhost-com1234-whereas-request-url-host)

Comment: I've had a look at that one, but I don't have that Cassini thing and it didn't otherwise yield anything usefull. The solution isn't viable anyway.

Comment: Do you use IIS Express? Does `Request.Headers["host"]` contain the correct value?

Comment: No, just the built in one in VS.

Comment: That is either IIS Express or ASP.NET Development Server, and [both seem to suffer from this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513216/test-multiple-domains-using-asp-net-development-server).

Comment: How absolutely horrible.. ``Request.Headers["host"]`` is right, but ``Request.Url.Host`` isn't. This opens up a world of hurt, cause I'm blessed with SiteCore and some other things.